# Error 404 not found when send request with post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http-status-code-404

I got err: POST http://xyz:3000/upload 404 (Not Found) .
In the client side I send a request (sorry I cannot public the real url):

```
$scope.upload = function (files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var text = '';
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                text = reader.result;
                $http.post('http://xyz:3000/upload', { 

                    file: { 
                        content: text, 
                        name: file.name, 
                        username: window.user.username
                    }
                })
                .success(function(file_name){
                    $scope.log = 'File ' + file_name + ' is uploaded successfully!' + '\n';
                    $scope.log += 'You can use ' + file_name + ' dataset now.';
                });
            }
            reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
```

and in the server side:

```
'use strict';

    module.exports = function(app) {
        var upload = require('../../app/controllers/upload.server.controller');

        app.route('/upload')
            .post(upload.create);
```

Could anybody help? It works in local but doesnt when I push these code to my server.

Comment: And you have write access on the server

Comment: any error other than 404 shown in console?

Comment: @adeneo  yes. It extractly the same code to the local but doesnt work ( except the url in the local is : http://localhost:3000/upload )